# Angular HTML TD class

Tags: angular

I have the below td with 10 columns. I want to underline first 4 columns but not underline remaining 6. Can anyone help me how to accomplish this.

```html
<tr>
  <td *ngFor="let column of Columns; let i=index;" class="cell-underline">
    <span>{{column.value}}</span>
  </td>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally add the class:

```
<td *ngFor="let column of Columns; let i=index;" [class.cell-underline]="i < 4">
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the directive ngFor and add a condition class. This is an example for you:

```html
<td *ngFor="let column of columns; index as i;">
  <span [ngClass]="{'underline': i < 5 }">{{column.value}}</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
<tr>
      <td *ngFor="let column of columns; let i=index;" [ngClass]="{cellUnderline: i<4}">
        <span>{{column.value}}</span>
      </td>
</tr>
```